# Plot raster by nrow and ncol (dimensions) in R

Tags: r, plot, raster

I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to change the x and y axes from coordinates (extent) to nrow and ncol (dimension). When I plot a raster:

```
r1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, crs="EPSG:4326")
values(r1) <- sample(80:100, 100, replace=TRUE)
plot(r1)
```

[image]

The x and y axes are pulling from `crs`. I want x and y to be based on the number of rows and columns:

[image]

Seems like there should be an obvious solution and I'm just not finding it. I checked [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/plot) on `plot()`, led me to `graphical parameters`, no luck. I tried forcing the axes with `ymn, ymx, xmn, xmx`. I thought to remove the `crs`, but that's just making things messy. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had it with setting the values for the extent of the raster.  The number columns and rows sets the resolution in `raster()`, but not the extent.
I believe that by default the extent in `raster()` is the extent of the Earth so -90, +90 for latitude and -180, +180 for longitude.  Here's an example:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(42)

r1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, crs="EPSG:4326")
values(r1) <- sample(80:100, 100, replace=TRUE)
plot(r1) ##Default Extent of xmn = -90, xmx=+90, ymn=-180, ymx=+180
```

[image]

```
r2 <- raster(xmn=0, xmx=10, ymn=0, ymx=10, ncol=10, nrow=10, crs="EPSG:4326")
values(r2) <- sample(80:100, 100, replace=TRUE)
plot(r2) ##Desired Extent of xmn = 0, xmx=10, ymn = 0, ymx = 10
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! Duh. With this insight I figured I can just reset the extent of my original raster: `extent(r1) <- extent(0, 10, 0, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the pixel position you could convert your raster to a matrix and plot it using `image` or `rasterVis::levelplot`

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
r1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, crs="EPSG:4326")
values(r1) <- sample(80:100, 100, replace=TRUE)

m <- as.matrix(r1)
```

```
image(1:ncol(m), 1:nrow(m), m)
```

[image]

```r
rasterVis::levelplot(m)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is also helpful, gracias!